# How to debug Xamarin UWP project with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.uwp

While debugging a Xamarin UWP project, I notice a set of numbers in the upper left-hand corner of my debug screen. I have ignored them for quite some time but am curious about what relevance these numbers provide and how to turn them off. I find them of no value. Below is a sample of my test.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

That's the windows frame rate counter. If you want to disable it, go to your `App.xaml.cs` file and remove/comment out the following code from the `OnLaunched` method:

```
#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif
```

For more,check document [DebugSettings Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.DebugSettings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22621#Windows_UI_Xaml_DebugSettings_EnableFrameRateCounter).